# Angular : ng-include were auto annotated when page loaded

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i use the ng-include to separate the html page , but when i load the page , the ng-include were auto annotated , i don't know what's happened on ng-include .

code :

```
<body>

    <div ng-include="templates/header.html"></div>

    <ul>
        <li><a ui-sref="home">home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">about</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ui-view></div>

    <div ng-include="templates/footer.html"></div>

</body>
```

after loading :

```
<body>

    <!--

     ngInclude: templates/header 

    -->
    <ul></ul>
    <!--

     uiView:  

    -->
    <div class="ng-scope" ui-view=""></div>
    <!--

     ngInclude: templates/footer 

    -->

</body>
```

it's werid and made me confused ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use like this

```
<div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>

<ul>
    <li><a ui-sref="home">home</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="about">about</a></li>
    <li><a ui-sref="contact">contact</a></li>
</ul>

<div ui-view></div>

<div ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></div>
```

> data-ng-include="'{filePath}'" **(single quotes)**

**if that will not work try to track the request using browser developer tools**

Comment: it works ! so angular think the double quotes "" means annotation？

Comment: you can get the full reference about ng-include from here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude